Как рассчитать нагрузку на хостинге из нагрузки на CPU?
У хостера есть ограничения по нагрузке на разных тарифах: нагрузка на CPU от 100 до 650.
Можно ли как-то эти данные перевести в траффик?
Чтобы понимать, скольких посетителей выдержит хостинг.
Сайт без базы данных на голом html/css/js.

Ну тогда это вопрос к хостингу, сколько процессора жрёт его веб-сервер при отдаче html/css/js файлов
